# Making a Mute Toggle Button Using NSUserDefaults and AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, avaudioplayer

I've been working on this project for a while, but I've encountered a problem that I can't figure out.

First, I have a checkbox button that saves to NSDefaultUser as BOOL value. It simply saves the value YES when it's pressed once and it saves NO if pressed again and so on... This checkbox button works fine like a normal custom checkbox button would.

I would like to make an option to mute all of my sounds in my app by using this checkbox button.

I'm playing my sounds by calling method such as:

```
- (void)startMusic1
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/music1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
    else
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

So for every sound I want to play in my app, I could repeat something like:

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *default = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(![default boolForKey:@"isMuted"])
    {
        [self startMusic1];
    }
}
```

But, this gets repetitive especially because I have to manage a lot of different sounds (and different buttons that play sounds) for my project, and it seems irrelevant to repeat these steps.

I tried making a new class with a subclass of AVAudioPlayer and messed around with -(BOOL)play method for a few days, but I couldn't manage to get the results I wanted. I researched and found posts like [Disable in App sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441504/disable-in-app-sounds) but this still wouldn't do it.

I'm pretty new to programming overall, so it'll be great if someone could enlighten me a little.

Answer (score 0):

I tackle this (rightly or wrongly, but it works for me) by using a global model singleton. This is a class that effectively maintains state across the entire application.

The way to do that is with a class that has a shared static property like this:

//// Interface

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AudioModel
@property (nonatomic) BOOL playAudio;
+(id)sharedInstance;

@end
```

//// Implementation

```
#import "AudioModel.h"

@implementation AudioModel

// property for toggling audio on or off
@synthesize playAudio = _playAudio;

// singleton model variable
static AudioModel* audio = nil;

-(BOOL)playAudio {
    return _playAudio;
}

-(void)setPlayAudio:(BOOL)playAudio {
    _playAudio = playAudio;
}

// static 
+(AudioModel*)sharedInstance {
    if(audio == nil)
    {
        audio = [[AudioModel alloc]init];
    }

    return audio;
}

-(AudioModel*)init {

    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        // set up default sounds on
        // this may read from your stored value  
        _playAudio = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Then when you want to read or write to this globally available singleton model, you set a variable in your controller like this:

```
AudioModel *volumeControl = [AudioModel sharedInstance];

if(volumeControl.playAudio){
   // method to play audio passing audio file name... 
}
```

You could also have a reference to your AVAudioPlayer instance in this class, init it on creation of the shared instance and pass files to it to play when required.